# Doctest not working in Sphinx, cannot import python files Python

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sys, pathlib, doctest

I have a problem trying to run `doctest` from the [Sphinx Tutorial](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/tutorial/describing-code.html). I have the directory tree below but I cannot run a `doctest` for `lumache.py`. How would be able to make it so that `lumache.py` is importable with the `pathlib` function in `conf.py` which is `sys.path.insert(0, pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[2].resolve().as_posix())`.The code I am trying to execute is of the same one from the tutorial (hyperlink mentioned in the first sentence).

**conf.py Contents**

```
# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here.
import pathlib
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[2].resolve().as_posix())

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.duration',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
]

...
```

**Contents of** `lumache.py`

```
def get_random_ingredients(kind=None):
    return ["shells", "gorgonzola", "parsley"]
```

**CMD execution**

```
C:\docs>make doctest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lumache'
```

**Directory Tree:**

```
docs/
├─build/
│ ├─doctest/
│ │ └─0 folder(s), 1 file(s)
│ ├─doctrees/
│ │ └─0 folder(s), 3 file(s)
│ └─html/
│   └─3 folder(s), 7 file(s)
├─make.bat
├─Makefile
└─source/
  ├─conf.py
  ├─index.rst
  ├─lumache.py
  ├─usage.rst
  ├─_static/
  │ └─0 folder(s), 0 file(s)
  └─_templates/
    └─0 folder(s), 0 file(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `lumache.py` to your project folder (i.e. same folder as where `docs/` currently is).

Comment: thank you that worked. By any chance do you know how to modify the `sys.path.insert(0, pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[2].resolve().as_posix())`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).